# How to call articles, online courses, educational videos with one phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

I want to write a sentence "You can put any ... on our platform". ... is a phrase that would mean articles, online courses, educational videos, etc.

1) What would be the appropriate phrase?

2.1) Is "learning materials" too narrow for the intended meaning?
2.2) Is "educational content" too formal?

Comment: "Here media!  Come here, media!  Ah, that's a good media!"

Comment: Can you put Apple iBooks on your platform?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

*TEACHING AIDS* .

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teaching%20aids)

***teaching aid***

noun

: an object 
(such as a book, picture, or map) 
or device (such as a dvd or computer)
 used by a teacher to enhance or enliven classroom instruction

// audiovisual teaching aids