# Word for "learning resources"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that encompasses any learning resources -- for example an article, video, podcast, book, course, etc.? Something that you learn from, but not a living thing such as a teacher...

Comment: Generally stuff like this is called "educational materials".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call articles, online courses, educational videos with one phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493410/how-to-call-articles-online-courses-educational-videos-with-one-phrase)

Answer (score 0):

You could use "educational resources" or just "sources" given the right context surrounding the term.